# Moving IMAP mailbox from a Linux server to G Suite

Tags: migration, mx-record, imap, g-suite, a-record

I have my old mailbox, which was hosted by my hosting provider. I want to move it to a new one, like G Suite.

To access my old email, I used `imap.mydomain.com` server.

I now moved my site to a new provider, so I changed the A-records to point to the new server. Therefore, as I understand, I cannot access my old `imap.mydomain.com` because it points to the new IP.

Do you know what I could do, which records I could change, to temporarily point `imap.mydomain.com` to my old server, so I could access it via IMAP protocol and use the new email hosting provider migration tool (either G Suite or any other)?

Should I add the A-record for `imap.mydomain` and point it to the old server and keep the MX records as they used to be (the old server as well) and migrate the data? Or I don't have to change the A-record and I can just do with the existing MX records unchanged?

Comment: Rather than using the hostname imap.example.com , use the ip-address (of the imap server at the old provider) to connect to the old server with your imap client...

Comment: @HBruijn ok, so that's going to work then. maybe you want to post it as an answer so I accept it. thanks.